# Child passport expired. Travel to Mexico

Tags: usa, international-travel, us-citizens, passport-renewals

I (21) am traveling to Mexico by plane with my younger sister (11) to visit family. We leave in two days, but just found out that her passport is expired. We are both US citizens. With her passport expired, will she be able to come back to the US if we take her expired passport and provide other documents that prove she is a citizen, such as a birth certificate and SSN?

Please help, I don’t think there would be enough time in two days to renew her passport and get it back.

Comment: How are you traveling? Flying, driving, something else?

Comment: "will she be able to come back to the US" Never mind coming back: if you are flying you won't be able to board the plane to Mexico.

Comment: @dda Unless she’s a dual national and has a foreign passport.

Comment: @RoboKaren Very true. But from the question, with the OP stating "We are both US citizens" I assumed single citizenship and no other passport. But we know that thing about assumptions, right? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that your case qualifies, but it is possible to renew a US passport in 24hrs, which you should try to do for your sister.
https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/hurry.html

Comment: A passport agency will generally issue a passport within a couple of hours of the appointment, if you have provided proof of imminent international travel and there aren't any complications with your application.